# DataTables ajax don't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

I have [This](http://jsfiddle.net/roybarak/gdcdynqe/) table which i'm trying to add ajax by adding this code :

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    'serverSide': true,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "info": false,
    "iDisplayLength":20,
    "bLengthChange":false,
    'ajax': {
        type: 'GET',
        'url': 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/ftw5f',
        'data': function(data) {
            return data;
        }
    },
    "columns": [{
        "data": 'Name'
    }, {
        "data": 'Position'
    }, {
        "data": 'Office'
    },
        {
            "data": 'Age'
        },
        {
            "data": 'Start date'
        },
        {
            "data": 'Salary'
        },

    ],

    initComplete: function () { // the filters });
```

When it's hard coded - like in fiddle - it's working - but when i add the ajax - and remove all the hard coded tr's - the filters don't work.... i checked the console for errors - but there are none.... thanks.

Comment: look in your network tab in the console, is the request being made to the server? If so, what is the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is with the property `'serverSide': true`. Once you set this, the search is no longer happening on the client, but on the server, hence you need to write server-side code to handle the search and return a subset of results. If you want to get data from an ajax source, and still process on the client, just delete the `serverSide` flag.

See working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kennasoft/gdcdynqe/2/)

Comment: Thanks - so when do i use 'serverSide': true?

Comment: You use `serverSide: true` when you have a huge dataset (maybe 1million records) you don't want to load into the page. This sends all the search and sort criteria back to the server, where you write code to handle these operations and send a response back to the front end.

Answer (score 1):

Your `columns` declaration is incorrect, the right side should be the *key* whose value should appear in that column not a *label* for that column.

If your data is like:

```
{
  name: '',
  position: '',
  office: '',
  age: '',
  start_date: '',
  salary: '',
}
```

Then columns should look like:

```
"columns": [{
    "data": 'name'
  }, {
    "data": 'position'
  }, {
    "data": 'office'
  }, {
    "data": 'age'
  }, {
    "data": 'start_date'
  }, {
    "data": 'salary'
  },
],
```

See the docs for more info: https://datatables.net/manual/ajax#Column-data-points